# How to return id from function in webmethod to javascript code

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, web-services

I have this javascript function to insert data using JSON

```
function Create(Name,Description) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.Name = Name;
    obj.Description = Description;
    $.ajax
        ({
            type: "Post",
            url: "/test.asmx/Create",
            dataType: 'JSON',
            contentType: "application/Json; Charset= Utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            success: function () {
                alert("Great");
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
}
```

And this my `WebMethod` in my web service I need to get the id of data inserted in my javascript code

```
[WebMethod]
public int Create(string Name, string Description)
{
    try
    {
        var Qer = new DAL.MOD.TABLE1
        {
            kName = Name,
            Description = Description
        };
        t.Create(Qer);
        return Qer.Id;
    }
    catch
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any a suggestion how to achieve this?

Comment: So u need to get the Qer.Id in JavaScript which you are returning from the service?

Comment: @prathameshk73 yes

Answer (score 0):

If ajax call and the web method works fine then you can access the result through success function of the ajax code;

```
 success: function (result) {
                                alert(result);
                            },
```

In the above snippet, result parameter should have the Id value which is returned from the web method.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Id in the **ajax success** function. If it goes into error function then you need to check your service.

```js
function Create(Name,Description) {
                var obj = {};
                obj.Name = Name;
                obj.Description = Description;
                $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: "Post",
                        url: "/test.asmx/Create",
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        contentType: "application/Json; Charset= Utf-8",
                        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                        success: function (response) {
                          if (response) {
                            // Query Id
                            alert(response);
                          }
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response);
                        }
                    });
            }
```

Comment: Try console.log(response) instead of alert. You should see Id in the console.

Comment: jquery returns a xhr object. You can't just display or use the object as a response.  You have to use the .d method  of  the object retuned to pluck out the data  as per  my response below.  EVEN if you set the response type as text, a xhr object is STILL returned, and you STILL need to use the .d method of the xhr object to get  the data  returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Create(Name,Description) {
                var obj = {};
                obj.Name = Name;
                obj.Description = Description;
                $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: "Post",
                        url: "/test.asmx/Create",
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        contentType: "application/Json; Charset= Utf-8",
                        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert(response.d);
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response);
                        }
                    });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as others noted, you need to create/setup/have a function that gets called back when the async call is done. You can use the function() in-line and that works just fine. So a WHOLE new function()  is created on the fly.

Next up?
You can't just use "response", but have to use ".d" for data.

Thus this will work:

```
   $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: 'WebForm1.aspx/HelloWorld',
        contentType: "application/json",  
        datatype: "json",  
        success: function(responseFromServer) {  
            alert(responseFromServer.d)  
        }  
    });  
}
```

Note the .d to get data out of the response object.

And if you return two values?
Say this:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string[] HelloWorld()
{
string[] twovalues = new string[2];
twovalues[0] = "This is the first return value";
twovalues[1] = "This is the second return value";

return twovalues;
```

}

So, now you can get at the two return values like this:

```
   $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: 'WebForm1.aspx/HelloWorld',
        contentType: "application/json",  
        datatype: "text",  
        success: function(responseFromServer) {  
            alert(responseFromServer.d[0]);
            alert(responseFromServer.d[1]);
        }  
    });
```

So the response is a object returned. You use the ".d" method of the response object to get at the data. And as per above, if more then one value is returned, then you can use the [] array reference to pluck out/grab each value returned.